# Is it possible to implement a BroadcastReceiver as a singleton if it's to be registered in the manifest?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a BroadcastReceiver which is to be registered under  as an application component in the manifest.

I'd like to ensure that there is only one instance of this class. Is it possible to enforce a singleton pattern for this class? Making the constructor private in this case doesn't work because the system is then unable to instantiate it, and returns a NullPointerException.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to make it a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to enforce a singleton pattern for this class?

No, sorry. The framework will create one instance per received broadcast, and that is not changeable, given that you are registering for it in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks. I think what I'll do is defer all the logic to another singleton class.

Comment: @zzazzles: Yeah, IMHO, a `BroadcastReceiver` should be a thin class, one that delegates any heavy lifting to something more appropriate (e.g., scheduling work in `WorkManager`). Bear in mind that `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread, so you don't want to do anything slow there anyway.